# How to increase run time for cronjobs?

Tags: cron, vercel, trpc

#### Summary

Within my `src/pages/api/crons/analytics/test.ts` I have this

```
import { prisma } from '../../../../server/db'
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

// https://vercel.com/docs/functions/serverless-functions/runtimes#maxduration
export const config = {
  maxDuration: 300
}



export default async function handler(request: NextApiRequest, response: NextApiResponse) {
  console.log('now: ', new Date())
  console.log('waiting 30 seconds...')
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 30000))

  console.log('waiting ANOTHER I 30 seconds...')
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 30000))

  console.log('waiting ANOTHER II 30 seconds...')
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 30000))

  console.log('waiting THE LAST 30 seconds...')
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 30000))

  console.log('runtime final: ', new Date())
  response.status(200).json({
    success: true
  })
}
```

This is my `vercel.json`

```
{
  "crons": [
    {
      "path": "/api/crons/analytics/test",
      "schedule": "0 15 * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, it times out after 15 seconds. **My organization is on the `Pro` tier.**

I'm following  this part of the documentation: https://vercel.com/docs/functions/serverless-functions/runtimes#maxduration

I've added the `config.maxDuration` but it still says 15s.